# A6100 wifi adapter not installing correctly with known techniques

Tags: networking

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and a A6100 wifi adapter. I've tried using Chilli's recommendations and when I get to github in terminal I'm asked for a username and password. I'm now stuck. Can someone help me please with compiling this driver rtl8812au? Preferably a step by step if you can? I have a very limited internet connection thru tethering. It only lasts for 5 minutes at a time. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Oh sorry for beating a dead horse as it were.

Comment: Happy to help! Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `uname -r` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu,

Comment: Lsusb shows a bunch of peripherals. My nether a6100 shows as well. With realtek rtl8811AU

Comment: Uname -r shows 5.13.0-30-generic

Comment: The reason I asked for `lsusb` is to see the *exact* usb.id; something like 2357:010e or some such. May I see it please?

Comment: Sure. Bus 008 Device 003: ID 0846:9052 Netgear, Inc. A6100 DB Wireless Adapter

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the end of the string. It reads Realtek RTL8811AU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git build-essential dkms bc
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install
sudo modprobe 88XXau
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: I get a fatal: destination path 'rtl8812au' already exists and is not an empty directory

Comment: This isn't going to work. My phones tethering just got booted. Now it only works for 20 seconds. Not fast enough to type a command in terminal then connect to Ethernet to dl.

Comment: Remove the old inoperable file first. sudo rm -r rtl8812au and then try again.

Comment: It worked! Thank you thank you! Removing the old file and using your commands from the earlier comment worked. I'll come back to this should I need it.

Comment: Glad it's working. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour